# Question on the Euler's function

Tags: number-theory

Let $k\neq 1$, $2$ divide $p+1$, where $p$ is prime. If $\phi $ is the
Euler's function, then

1) Why $\gcd(\phi (k), (p-1))=2$?

2) For $k\neq 1, 2$ why is $\sum_{k\mid (p+1)}\phi (k)/2=(p-1)/2$?

Comment: For (2) how did you get $(p-1)/2$?

Comment: @user57106:
For the second one, recall the Euler classical formula
$$\sum_{d \vert n} \phi(d) = n$$
Hence, $$\phi(1) + \phi(2) + \sum_{d \vert n, d >2} \phi(d) = n \implies \sum_{d \vert n, d >2} \phi(d) = n-2$$

Comment: @Marvis The OP's formula above is wrong which is why I'm asking how he got $(p-1)/2$

Comment: @BenjaLim Yes. That was meant for the OP. Will update the post.

Comment: @user57106  (1) is not true either. Take $p=29$, then $\phi(30)= (2-1)(3-1)(5-1) = 8$ and $p-1 = 28$, so their gcd is 4. It might be true that the gcd is a (positive integral) power of 2.

Comment: @BenjaLim I edited the question to match the one posted to MathOverflow (and deservedly punted here).

Comment: Take $p=139$, then $\phi(140) = 2(2-1)(3-1)(7-1)$ is a multiple of 3, and $138$ is a multiple of 3, so the gcd need not be a power of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of comments:

(1) was disproved by Calvin Lin. Take $p=29$, then $\phi(30)=(2−1)(3−1)(5−1)=8$ and $p−1=28$, so their gcd is $4$. Furthermore, gcd need not be a power of $2$: take p=139, then $\phi(140)=2(2−1)(3−1)(7−1)$ is a multiple of $3$, and $138$ is a multiple of $3$.

(2) was proved by user 17662 using Euler's [divisor sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Divisor_sum) $\sum_{d \vert n} \phi(d) = n$. Namely, write
$$\sum_{d \vert n, d >2} \phi(d) = n-\phi(1)-\phi(2)=n-2$$
and let $n=p+1$.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know Euler was a mathematician AND a time traveler!